# Can you define methods in the main 'public static void main(String[] args)' method in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to Java and have been practising programming within the Eclipse IDE. I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    public double absoluteValue(double n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return -n;
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(absoluteValue(-5));
}
```

I tried to create a method `absoluteValue()` which returns absolute values. However, Eclipse threw a bunch of errors at me.

I managed to get my code to work when I *defined* `absoluteValue()` *outside of the main method* (had to define it as `public static double absoluteValue(double n)` though) and *called it within the main method*.

But I was just wondering why the above code doesn't work. Can you define methods within the main method (if so, should you)?

Answer (score 3):

Java does not allow nesting of methods of this sort.  You can have lambdas inside of a method but you can't define a full method inside of a method.  This is an important difference for Pythonistas to know.

Comment: *"This is an important difference for Pythonistas to know."* And schemers, and js-ers, and... :)

Comment: Unless...  lambdas :-)

Comment: You could define a local class inside a method though, and since Java 17 (I think), local classes allow static methods... It is a dirty trick, but an option to define a full-fledged method inside a method. However, to be clear, it is better to write "normal" Java and not try to write Python in Java.